# How can I check the release of a package in debian?

Tags: debian, dpkg

I am planning to do an upgrade on my system and I have a mix of three releases, there are some packages from wheezy, some from jessie and some of stretch.
I would like to get the list of the packages with their release so I can do some purge before upgrading the system.

Comment: If you plan to upgrade the whole system to a single release, then what does it matter?

Comment: I have nginx,php5-fpm,mysql,python, ..., I'd rather upgrade it bit by bit :)

Comment: `I'd rather upgrade it bit by bit` - Debian isn't built to work that way.  You are almost certainly going to make a big mess.

Comment: I have never found anything that was great, but someone came up witha python script. 
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185698/1209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `apt-show-versions` (available in the package with the same name) might be the tool you are looking for.

Comment: I just installed it, it's mostly what I needed, the only drawback is that it's pretty slow to run, I hoped something with dpkg+flags would have been possible

Comment: @Aseques I don’t think dpkg tracks the origin of packages; as I understand it, only apt does.